# SQL distinct in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have two tables which don't have any relation or foreign key,I want to combine two columns in my query.

```
 select   DISTINCT a.OdemeTuru, b.MAdi from odemeturu as a, 
 musteriler as b order by b.MID,a.OID
```

I can get values from both but it's mixed and distinct is not working.

The result is as follows:

```
'Nakit', 'Ali' 'Veresiye', 'Ali' 'Kredi Kartı', 'Ali' 'Özel', 'Ali'
'Nakit', 'Ahmet' 'Veresiye', 'Ahmet' 'Kredi Kartı', 'Ahmet' 'Özel',
'Ahmet' 'Nakit', 'Cemil' 'Veresiye', 'Cemil' 'Kredi Kartı', 'Cemil'
'Özel', 'Cemil' 'Nakit', 'Furkan' 'Veresiye', 'Furkan' 'Kredi Kartı',
'Furkan' 'Özel', 'Furkan'
```

However, I want the following

```
'Nakit', 'Ali'
'Özel', 'Ahmet'
'Veresiye', 'Cemil'
'Kredi Kartı', 'Furkan'
```

Where is mistake in my query? (table' row counts are same)

Edit: sorry I forgot some thing. there isnt exist a.tarih

Comment: What's the table structure for your tables `odemeturu` and `musteriler`?

Comment: museriler==> MID (int), MAdi (nvarchar)   odemeturu==> OID(int), OdemeTuru (nvarchar)

Comment: What data do the 2 tables have? (add that in your question). How many rows each? (4 I guess)

Comment: yes for now there are 4 rows each table

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of to cross apply 2 tables of 4 rows to get 4 rows and not 16 is to join on a rownumber:

```
SELECT  a.OdemeTuru, b.Madi
FROM    (   SELECT  @a:= @a + 1 AS RowNumber, OID, OdemeTuru
            FROM    odemeturu,
                    (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a
            ORDER BY OID
        ) AS a
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  @b:= @b + 1 AS RowNumber, MID, Madi
            FROM    musteriler,
                    (SELECT @b:= 0) AS b
            ORDER BY MID
        ) AS b
            ON a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber
```

In `odemeturu` the rows are ordered by OID, and the rows in `musteriler` ordered by MID. The first row of `odemeturu` is joined with the first row of `musteriler`, the second with the second and so on. This is fairly arbitrary but seems to match your criteria.

You can change how the subqueries are ordered to change the results.

---

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d32a2/1)**

Answer (score 0):

If you can join both your tables somehow then you can probably do like this:

```
select   DISTINCT a.OdemeTuru, b.MAdi from odemeturu a leftjoin musteriler b 
on a.OID = b.MID order by b.MID,a.OID a.tarih
```

**EDIT:**

As stated, without any relationship between the tables and MID/OID are also different; the only thing possible would be get all different values using `UNION` like

```
select DISTINCT OdemeTuru from odemeturu order by a.OID,a.tarih 
UNION
select distinct MAdi from musteriler order by b.MID
```

Comment: Rahul, there isn any relation between to table like a.OID = b.MID

Comment: @HarunAbi, got it and that's why I specifically mentioned `If you can join both your tables`

Comment: ids are different but I want to combine them without similar field

Comment: @HarunAbi, see my edit. In such case, only possibility is `UNION` all the different values from both tables.

Comment: order by using is wrong (i got some error because of it) and when I remove order by I can get all records in one column. but I  need to take them two columns

Comment: @HarunAbi, In this case, this is what can be best achieved.

Comment: I just did it with sql query. I think I have to use programming functions if its not possible ::S thank you for interesting..